# Pandas DataFrame reset cache

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I'm having trouble when working with `pandas` `DataFrame`. Consider following `DataFrame`:
[image: table]

Now if I were to use `seaborn` [`FacetGrid`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.FacetGrid.html) to plot multiple subplots. In this case subplots are based on column `scale`. It correctly creates only 2 subplots because there are only two unique values in column `scale`:

Simple code:

```
print(df['scale'].value_counts())
print(set(df['scale']))
```

Will produce:

```
weak      960
strong    890
Name: scale, dtype: int64
{'weak', 'strong'}
```

Example of generated figure:

```
g = seaborn.FacetGrid(df, row='scale')
g.map(plt.plot, 'proc', 'wall_avg')
```

[image: correct]

Problem comes when I try to filter rows. If I filter out all rows where column `scale` value is `weak` I should get figure with only one subplot but I have still 2 subplots even though `DataFrame` does not contain any other `scale`.

```py
# filter rows
df = df[['scale'] == 'weak']
# print details about column scale
print(df['scale'].value_counts())
print(set(df['scale']))
```

Will produce:

```
weak      960
strong      0
Name: scale, dtype: int64
{'weak'}
```

And resulting figure contains empty subplot:

[image: wrong]

I do not know if this behavior is the correct one but I would prefer to not have empty subplot. Is there any way to reload `DataFrame`?
[`reset_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) is does not work.

So far I can reload `DataFrame` by saving it into csv and reloading it again which is not pretty.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: What is `print (df['scale'].dtype)` ?

Comment: I'm using `category` dtype

Comment: Then check answer, it is exactly what need.

Comment: Yes looking at it right now, thank for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `scale` column must be a `categorical` dtype.  After filtering, you need to call [`remove_unused_categories()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.cat.remove_unused_categories.html):

```
df = df[['scale'] == 'weak']
df.scale.cat.remove_unused_categories(inplace=True)
```

Comment: Yes, that indeed works. Thanks for the quick response!